# Converting a string to an Integer in C

Tags: beginner, c, integer

I'm learning C and one of the questions I've been asked is converting a string to an integer. The code I've written supports converting from a string in any base up to 16/hex to an integer. There is no  over/underflow checking and it does not support lowercase hex.

```
int ASCIIToInteger(char *x, int base)
{
    //Each element is the ASCII for it's index. 
    int ASCIICodes[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };  _Bool negative = 0;
    int count = 0, output = 0;  
    if (x[0] == '-')
    {
        negative = 1;
        count = 1;
    }
    else if (x[0] == '+')
    {
        count = 1;
    }
    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < base; i++)
        {               
            if (ASCIICodes[i] == (int)x[count])
            {
                output = output * base + i;
                break;
            }
        }
        count++;
    } while (x[count] != 0);

    if (negative == 1)
    {
        return ~output + 1;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Can I please get some advice regarding any possible issues or "rookie mistakes" I may have made?

Comment: Is this intended to be reinventing the [`strtol`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3792676) [(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) function?

Comment: @Mast I wasn't aware of the function at the time but looking at the description I guess it is.

Comment: There is also atoi (string to integer) and atof (string to double) for plain old string-to-numeric conversion.

Comment: for readability and understandability by us humans, please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement

Comment: I would modify the declaration of `ASCIICodes[]` to add the `const modifier.

Comment: Consider writing unit tests for a function like this.  There are a lot of special cases (no digits, too many digits, non-digits, leading zeroes, etc.) that aren't handled.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Avoid mysterious bit-shifting**

```
return ~output + 1;
```

Is the same as:

```
return - (output + 1) + 1;
```

And as:

```
return - output;
```

But the last one is way more obvious than the first one.

**Do not hide variable declarations**

```
int ASCIICodes[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };  _Bool negative = 0;
```

If I look at the above line, the least thing in my mind is that a variable is defined after that list.

If a user has a small screen or a big font size he will be very puzzled when he will see you use `negative` without seeing its definition.

Just use a newline, they are free:

```
int ASCIICodes[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
_Bool negative = 0;
```

**Make variables as local as possible**

I used `x++` to express that I will skip the first character:

```
if (x[0] == '-')
{
    negative = true;
    x++;
}
else if (x[0] == '+')
{
    x++;
}
```

This allows me to make `count` local.

**Using `for` loops when practical**

The outer of your loops is a `do` `while`, but looking around I found all three components of a `for` loop, just shuffled into the code.

A `for` loop will give it more organization:

```
for (int count = 0; x[count] != 0; count++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < base; i++)
    {               
        if (ASCIICodes[i] == x[count])
        {
            output = output * base + i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Simplify the initial conditional**

Assigning a boolean to `negative` directly and using a `||` conditional looks shorter and simpler:

We go from:

```
_Bool negative = 0;
int count = 0, output = 0;  
if (x[0] == '-')
{
    negative = 1;
    count = 1;
}
else if (x[0] == '+')
{
    count = 1;
}
```

to:

```
bool negative = x[0] == '-';

if (x[0] == '-' || x[0] == '+')
{
    x++;
}
```

While preserving identical functionality.

#### [`it's` vs `its`](http://its-not-its.info)

> ... How to choose between it's and its?
>
> This is actually really easy, do you mean "it is" or not?

Use `it's` when you mean `it is`.

```
// Each element is the ASCII for it's index.
```

Here you should write `its` because you mean possession, intended as a property of the element.

Saying that:

```
// Each element is the ASCII for it is index.
```

Makes no sense.

So the correct comment will be:

```
// Each element is the ASCII for its index.
```

Comment: I love the grammar police in this answer. I get sick of reading that mistake over and over in forums, texts, IMs, etc. Now I know _it's_ in one less program, thanks to you!

Comment: the other reason to avoid "mysterious bit shifting" is that (AFAICR) the use of two's complement representation of negative numbers is not actually mandated by the standard.

Comment: @Alnitak kind of... non-two-complement machines are pretty arcane -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276957/are-there-any-non-twos-complement-implementations-of-c

Comment: Arcane, but legal ;)  In any event it's better just to let the compile do the right thing and just express negation using the operator intended for that purpose.

Comment: "it's" is also a contraction of "it has" -- it's been fun

Answer (score 12):

#### Write one statement per line

Avoid multiple statements on the same line, for example instead of:

> ```
> int ASCIICodes[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' }; _Bool negative = 0;
> ```

Break that up to multiple lines:

```
int ASCIICodes[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
_Bool negative = 0;
```

This is because it's easier to read from top to bottom.
If there are statements at the end of lines,
that can be very distracting.

#### Eliminate pointless cast

No need to cast to `int` here:

> ```
> if (ASCIICodes[i] == (int)x[count])
> ```

#### Simplify `ASCIICodes`

A simpler way to define `ASCIICodes`:

```
char ASCIICodes[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

#### Simplify using a ternary operator

Instead of this:

> ```
> if (negative)
> {
>     return ~output + 1;
> }
> return output;
> ```

You could simplify using the ternary operator:

```
return negative ? -output : output;
```

Or perhaps instead of a `bool negative`, you could use an `int sign`:

```
int sign = 1;
int count = 0, output = 0;  
if (x[0] == '-')
{
    sign = -1;
    count = 1;
}
// ....
return sign * output;
```

#### Use `bool` from `stdbool`

Although using `_Bool` is ok,
it would be a good idea to `#include <stdbool.h>`,
which defines `bool` (expands to `_Bool`) and `true` and `false`,
for example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int ASCIIToInteger(char *x, int base)
{
    // ....
    bool negative = false;
    // ...
    if (x[0] == '-')
    {
        negative = true;
        count = 1;
    }

    // ...

    if (negative)
    {
        return ~output + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't check for non-number characters. The sign is in the while-loop silently ignored, as any other symbol. What is the number of "HELLO" in hex? 14.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that no-one has pointed out the O(m * base) complexity caused by the inner loop that performs a linear scan over the (unnecessary) `ASCIICodes` array.

This version of the outer loop removes the inner loop, supports lower cased characters, and also breaks the loop as soon as any illegal character is seen.

```
while ((n = x[count++])) {
    int ch = toupper((int)n);
    if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')) {
        int digit = ch - '0';
        if (digit > 9) {
            digit = 10 + ch - 'A';  // convert 'A' to 10, etc
        }
        if (digit < base) {
            output = output * base + digit;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Accept both cases by folding input through `toupper()`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
//...

    if (ASCIICodes[i] == toupper(x[count]))
```

But you can also define the set as a string and use `strchr` to do the searching.

Comment: Note: `(int)` in `toupper((int)x[count])` serves no purpose.

Comment: True, but if `toupper` is a macro, this will suppress the occasional warning about indexing with a char type.

Comment: The warning about "indexing with a char type" should _not_ be suppressed by casting to `int` when using  `toupper()`.  That leads to UB when `char` is signed.  Better to use `toupper((unsigned char)x[count])`.  C only defines `toupper()` for values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. I have removed the cast from my answer, and will be more cautious about this in future.

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int atoib(const char *x, int base)
{
    unsigned s = 0, v = 0;

    unsigned char c = *x++;
    if (c == '-')
        s++, c = *x++;
    else if (c == '+')
        c = *x++;

    if (base <= 10) {
        if (base >= 2) {
            unsigned M = '0' + base - 1;
            while (c >= '0' && c <= M) {
                v = v * base + c - '0';
                c = *x++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (base <= ('Z' - 'A' + 11)) {
            unsigned M = 'A' + base - 11;
            for (;;) {
                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                    v = v * base + c - '0';
                } else {
                    c = toupper(c);
                    if (c >= 'A' && c <= M)
                        v = v * base + c - 'A' + 10;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                c = *x++;
            }
        }
    }

    return (v ^ -s) + s;
}
```

Key points:

1. allow base values greater than 16;
2. check for valid base values (from 2 up to 36);
3. allow lowercase and uppercase digits (from a|A up to z|Z);
4. bail out on digits invalid for the given base and any non-digit;
5. avoid terminating null checks, the digit validation does it for free;
6. use arithmetic instead of lookup table to find the digit value (by the way, if you want to use a lookup table, then define it as static, otherwise it will be created on the stack and initialised on every invocation of your function);
7. the funny return expression saves one branch for two's-complement integers, if you are afraid of ever running on a non-two's-complement platform or just strive for clarity, then do `return s ? -v : v;` instead;

The proper handling of cases 2 and 4 still need some improvement, perhaps with `errno` assignment or by changing the interface to something akin to `strtol` or, if `C++` is allowed, by throwing an exception. Also it might make sense to handle integer overflow errors.

The test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
        atoib("10", 0), atoib("10", 1), atoib("10", 2), atoib("10", 9),
        atoib("10", 10), atoib("10", 11), atoib("10", 36), atoib("10", 37));
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
        atoib("8", 9), atoib("9", 9), atoib("9", 10), atoib("A", 10),
        atoib("A", 11), atoib("B", 11), atoib("Z", 36), atoib("[", 36));
    printf("%d %d\n", atoib("-2", 10), atoib("+2", 10));
    return 0;
}
```